# Placing auto-saves in a different folder doesn't work

Tags: auto-save

I am working on my personal emacs config and  I wanted to keep .emacs.d/ uncluttered. So I created a temp folder inside .emacs.d/ that includes a backup directory. This part works fine. Also sending backup files (tilde files) into the backup directory works, but this is not the case with my autosaves.

My code is:

`` (setq auto-save-file-name-transforms `((".*" ,db/backup-dir t))) (setq auto-save-list-file-prefix db/backup-dir) ``

The variable `db/backup-dir` is created before and works just fine, folder is also created.
Exchanging the variable to `~/.emacs.d/temp/backup/` does not help either.

I am running emacs 27. I have tried this on both linux and windows, the problem persists.
What am I doing wrong?